# RxJava: How to group arbitrary large number of items using my own boundary function

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an observable which emits strings, and I want to group them by first character. It's easy to do it with `groupBy` like that:

```
Observable<String> rows = Observable.just("aa", "ab", "ac", "bb", "bc", "cc");

Observable<List<String>> groupedRows = rows.groupBy(new Func1<String, Character>() {
  public Character call(String row) {
    return row.charAt(0);
  }
}).flatMap(new Func1<GroupedObservable<Character, String>, Observable<List<String>>>() {
  public Observable<List<String>> call(GroupedObservable<Character, String> group) {
    return group.toList();
  }
});

groupedRows.toBlocking().forEach(new Action1<List<String>>() {
  public void call(List<String> group) {
    System.out.println(group);
  }
});

// Output:
// [aa, ab, ac]
// [bb, bc]
// [cc]
```

But it's not good for my purposes, because `groupBy` only completes each group when the source observable emits `onComplete`. So if I have lots of rows, they will be completely gathered in memory and only at the very last row "flushed" and written to output.

I need something like `buffer` operator, but with my own function which denotes boundary of each group. I implemented it like that (knowing that rows are always ordered alphabeticaly):

```
Observable<String> rows = Observable.just("aa", "ab", "ac", "bb", "bc", "cc");

ConnectableObservable<String> connectableRows = rows.publish();

Observable<String> boundarySelector = connectableRows.filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
  private char lastChar = 0;

  public Boolean call(String row) {
    char currentChar = row.charAt(0);
    boolean isNewGroup = lastChar != 0 && (currentChar != lastChar);
    lastChar = currentChar;
    return isNewGroup;
  }
});

Observable<List<String>> groupedRows = connectableRows.buffer(boundarySelector);

connectableRows.connect();

groupedRows.toBlocking().forEach(new Action1<List<String>>() {
  public void call(List<String> group) {
    System.out.println(group);
  }
});

// Output:
// []
// []
// []
```

It doesn't work, because `boundarySelector` is "eating" the rows, and I think it's weird because I specifically used `ConnectableObservable` to denote that I need two subscribers (`boundarySelector` and `groupedRows`) before the `rows` start emitting.

Curiosly if I delay `rows` by 1 seconds, then this code works.

So the question is: how do I group arbitrary number of rows using my own boundary function?

Comment: Why don't you consume the GroupedObservables reactively instead of collecting their values into Lists?

Comment: Because I need all values from single group to construct single object, and this single object will be pushed further for reactive processing. The actual use case is that I have parent-child relationship in DB entities, I do SQL that joins those tables, so one row for each child is emmited. Then I want to group childs from same parent in a collection, build parent with it's childs, and emit this parent object.

Comment: "I need all values from single group to construct single object" - this sounds contradictory to me. If you need all values from each group, why do you want to chop the groups into parts? Btw, because you connect before subscribing, the whole thing rushes through and you get empty values. You'd need some auto-connection but such feature is currently under consideration in RxJava.

Comment: @akarnokd Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wgd/01c68420f1fe5e53090f), I've tried to explain there what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

```
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(0, 100);

source
.groupBy(k -> k / 10)
.publish(groups -> groups
        .map(g -> Pair.of(g.getKey(), g.takeUntil(groups)))
        .flatMap(kv -> 
            kv.second
            .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println(kv.first + " value " + v))
            .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println(kv.first + " done"))
        ))
.subscribe()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it using `buffer`:

```
Observable<String> rows = Observable.just("aa", "ab", "ac", "bb", "bc", "cc");

ConnectableObservable<String> connectableRows = rows.publish();

Observable<String> boundarySelector = connectableRows.filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
    private char lastChar = 0;

    public Boolean call(String row) {
        char currentChar = row.charAt(0);
        boolean isNewGroup = lastChar != 0 && (currentChar != lastChar);
        lastChar = currentChar;
        return isNewGroup;
    }
});

Observable<List<String>> groupedRows = connectableRows
        .refCount()
        .buffer(boundarySelector);

groupedRows.toBlocking().forEach(new Action1<List<String>>() {
    public void call(List<String> group) {
        System.out.println(group);
    }
});

// Output:
// [aa, ab, ac]
// [bb, bc]
// [cc]
```